# While (true) loop lagg

Tags: c#, sockets, loops, while-loop, freeze

Anyway I'm trying to make a Client connect to a Server using TCPListener and TCPClient
whenever i have the `while (true)` code, it freezes my whole application.

My code:

```
private void addSocket(int port)
{
    server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
    server.Start();
    client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
    sr = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
    sw = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
    toolStripStatusLabel2.Text = "waiting for connection";
    while (true)
    {
        toolStripStatusLabel2.Text = "client connected";
    }
    server.Stop();
    client.Close();
}
```

Comment: Sadly you should start a backgroundworker, or a thread

Comment: "Doctor, it hurts when I do this."                    
"Then don't do that."

Comment: What do you think an *infinite* loop will do? End in a while?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while(true)` is an infinite loop, the only way of getting out of it is using `break`. Or changing `while(true)` to some condition that alternatively ends.

In this code, the `while(true)` part makes no real sense to me, you should probably add something else to that part as well, e.g. some connection stuff etc.

Comment: well, i want it to be like when a new client has connected it shows a message, therefor i used the while (true)

Comment: If you remove the while(true) and keep only the message assignment, it would be more obvious what the code does. It will assign the message once; there is no difference in how many times you assign the message, it will be the same.

Comment: if i remove the while loop and when there is no client connected it shows this text "client connected";

Comment: while(true) doesn't make your client connected, it only doesn't show you that you aren't connecting it. You aren't using the stream reader and stream writer at all, shouldn't you use them?

Comment: i was about to use them after i fixed this freeze, and "while(true) doesn't make your client connected" it wasn't supposed to do that, if a client was connect it should execute that loop.

Comment: Then you'll need to add some condition if the client is connected there - current condition is `true`, which is pretty bad condition for checking something...

Answer (score 0):

That is because the `while (true)` never end. Add a condition that will return `false` at some point.

In this case the `while` doesn't make sense to me. What is your intent with it? Just start a `Task` or `BackgroundWorker` to process the stream.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need it to be All the time , do you?

```
  private void addSocket(int port)
{
server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
server.Start();
client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
sr = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
sw = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
toolStripStatusLabel2.Text = "waiting for connection";


    toolStripStatusLabel2.Text = "client connected";

server.Stop();
client.Close();
toolStripStatusLabel2.Text = "client not connected";
}
```

You just change a text for it. Then you could change it later!!.

Next time if you want to use while (true){}; consider using Thread

Comment: well, if i do this it shows the client connected text when there is no client connected?

Comment: @user3575640 then add toolStripStatusLabel2.Text = "client not connected"; after the connection was close. See my edit what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your program will run ok if you just delete `while` statement because i don't see any need of it in your code